# Read lines and add it to the list from an external text file c#

Tags: c#

what is the best possible way read and parse each parts line from an external text file and add it to the parts list. Here is the code below.

```
   List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();

    // Add parts to the list.
    parts.Add(new Part() {PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234});
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "regular seat", PartId = 1434 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "banana seat", PartId = 1444 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "cassette", PartId = 1534 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "shift lever", PartId = 1634 });
```

Here is what I am trying to do but it doesn't work.

```
  {
    var fileStream = new FileStream(@"~App_Data/file.text", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
      {
       string line;
       while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) {

           parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "", PartId= ""});

       }
  }
```

simple text file sample

```
new Part() {PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234};
new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 };
new Part() { PartName = "regular seat", PartId = 1434 };
new Part() { PartName = "banana seat", PartId = 1444 };
```

Comment: how partname and partid splited? with comma?

Comment: Please provide a sample of data in file.text file.

Comment: sample text file added

Comment: @user2178940, are you certain that is the text in the the file? Looks like you just copied the code snippet from higher up

Comment: Why is your data file not just a simple CSV or even XML or JSON?

Comment: because the second string is an long SQL statement. I was just typing to understand the concept. So there are basically 3 strings in text file on each line separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
string lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(MapPath(@"~/App_Data/file.text");
for(int i=0; i<lines.Lemgth; i++)
{
     Match m = Regex.Match(lines[i],"\{\s*PartName\s*=\s*\"([^\"]*)"\s*,\s*PartId\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*\}");
    if(m.Success) parts.Add(new Part(){PartName = m.Groups[1].Value, PartId = int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //references
        using System.IO;
        using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


        //code that goes in the method
        List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"~App_Data/file.text"))
        {
            parts.Add(new Part()
            {
                PartName = line.Split('"')[1],
                PartId = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value)
            });
        }
```